# how to disable future date and not scrolling datepicker in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I am using datepicker when user select current date not future date and     not scrolling date picker in swift 2.0

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    sender.inputView = datePickerView
    //datePickerView.minimumDate = datePickerView.date
    datePickerView.maximumDate = datePickerView.date

    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BookAppointmentView.datePickerValueChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    DatePickerField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this maximumdate property of datepicker. The maximumdate will be always the current date.

```
let DatePicker = UIDatePicker()
DatePicker.maximumDate = NSDate()
```

**Edit**
 You are doing it wrong.

```
// DatePicker.maximumDate = DatePicker.date //This is a wrong approach. It will not allow you from scrolling

DatePicker.maximumDate = NSDate() // This will avoid you from setting a future date.
```

Comment: i am already use this code but scrolling of datepicker is not stop(freeze).

Comment: Scrolling of date picker is default functionality, you can not freeze it. Only you can set minimum and maximum date or you can implement normal picker and add value in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following :

change **datePickerView.maximumDate** to **NSDate.date**

It wont allow to select future date. ie., maximum date you can select is today.

Hope it helps..

Comment: i am already use this code but scrolling of datepicker is not stop(freeze).

Comment: Scrolling can't be stoppable. It will scroll on future dates. But you can't select any future date. It will come to maximum date when you release scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

it is so simple. just maximumDate property in nsdatepicker as today date

self.datePicker.maximumDate = NSDate()

Comment: i am already use this code but scrolling of datepicker is not stop